# Remove script type attribute that is prepended by a dynamically changing string

Tags: wordpress, types, attributes, mime

On a WordPress website, I would like to remove a script "type" attribute that is dynamically prepended by a random string.
The form is type="xxx-text/javascript" where xxx changes on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Disable **Rocket Loader** on **CloudFlare**.

yourdomain.com > Speed > Optimization:

[image]